# Reshape using columns as categories

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

Any R code to reshape this data frame from:

|  | big | small | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 70.9 | 60.3 | 2000 |
| 2 | 70.7 | 40.4 | 2001 |
| 3 | 70.8 | 55.2 | 2002 |

to:

|  | size | values | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | big | 70.9 | 2000 |
| 2 | small | 60.3 | 2000 |
| 3 | big | 70.7 | 2001 |
| 4 | small | 40.4 | 2001 |
| 5 | big | 70.8 | 2002 |
| 6 | small | 55.2 | 2002 |

Is there a neat way to do it in base R (if not package solution is also ok)?

Any help appreciated thanks!

Comment: Please either check the tidyverse package (function `pivot_longer`) or the reshape2 package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R option

```
> cbind(year = df$year, rev(stack(df[1:2])))[order(c(row(df[1:2]))),]
  year   ind values
1 2000   big   70.9
4 2000 small   60.3
2 2001   big   70.7
5 2001 small   40.4
3 2002   big   70.8
6 2002 small   55.2
```

---

A `data.table` option

```
> setorder(melt(setDT(df), id.vars = "year"), "year")[]
   year variable value
1: 2000      big  70.9
2: 2000    small  60.3
3: 2001      big  70.7
4: 2001    small  40.4
5: 2002      big  70.8
6: 2002    small  55.2
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the `pivot_longer()` function from the `dplyr`package

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% pivot_longer(cols=c('big', 'small'), names_to='size', values_to='values'))
```

Answer (score 3):

As the OP mentioned `base R` solution, here is one with `reshape`

```
out <- reshape(df1, idvar = "year", direction = 'long',
    times = names(df1)[1:2], varying = list(1:2), timevar = "size", 
       v.names = "values")
row.names(out) <- NULL
```

-output

```
> out
  year  size values
1 2000   big   70.9
2 2001   big   70.7
3 2002   big   70.8
4 2000 small   60.3
5 2001 small   40.4
6 2002 small   55.2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(big = c(70.9, 70.7, 70.8), small = c(60.3, 40.4, 
55.2), year = 2000:2002), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```